# Medion Scanner MD90093

Tags: scanner

I have a Medion Scanner MD90093, how i can install this in Ubuntu 15.10 ?

I like to use with XSANE but the Program tell: NO SCANNER FOUND !

Thanks

Comment: I presume it's a USB scanner, yes?  Can you please include the output of `lsusb` in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try my Sane GUI, 
I named it ScanJet (I have a HP ScanJet 2300C), 
it should also work with other Sane Scanner.

[Download Linux Version](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uf6etzmluzj2hm0/ScanJetLinux.zip?dl=1)

[image: Screenshot]